# Oracle find non-default characters

Tags: oracle, character-encoding

I need to find non-default characters ([A-Z]) and characters with accents.

Because a import from Mysql was done, so not suported characters from the Mysql encoding can not be represented properly into Oracle.

Can REGEXP_LIKE be used to find the accents characters?

`SELECT * FROM clients WHERE !REGEXP_LIKE(name, '[A-Z] ');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`SELECT * FROM clients WHERE not REGEXP_LIKE(name, '[A-Z]*');`

Comment: Thank you for your help, i realize i need to find characters that i does not know like this one: ¿

 SELECT * FROM clients WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(convert(razaosocial, 'WE8ISO8859P1', 'utf8'), '¿');

Comment: Is there a way to find all characters that have the utf8 enconding ? because this is the encondig that came from the imported database. At the end they break pdf generation because Oracle does not represent this character

Comment: I need to find and then convert these characters from UTF8 to WE8ISO8859P1